# How To Change The Color Of The Actual Tool Bars Of Android Studios

Tags: android, colors, tabs, settings

I looked up this question and was unable to find it.  Anyways I was able to change the background color of the pages, AKA where you write your code. I just don't know how to change the color of the toolbars(and everything else at the top), if that's even possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can change theme of android studio if you want by following the steps

1. Go to File Menu
2. Click on Settings
3. Under Appearance and Behavior -> Select Appearance
4. Under UiOptions -> Dropdown Theme

By default only three themes are there

1. Dracula
2. IntelliJ
3. Platform Default( i.e. Windows)